# “error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant” is coming up to my code

Tags: c

I got this error when I try to run this c program:
the program has more 2 files that dont make problems.
maybe the problem dont conect to the define? may I make a constant diffrently?

header file:

```
#ifndef NUMBERGAME_H_
#define NUMBERGAME_H_
#define COLSIZE 4
#define ROWSIZE 5
void creatGameMatrix(int* mat,  int ROWSIZE , int COLSIZE);
void shuffleMatrix(int* mat, int ROWSIZE , int COLSIZE);
#endif /* NUMBERGAME_H_ */
```

cfile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "NumberGame.h"


//creat an ordered matrix N*M
void creatGameMatrix(int* mat, int ROWSIZE , int COLSIZE)
{
    int number = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWSIZE; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLSIZE; ++j) {
            mat [i][j] = number++;
        }
    }
}

void shuffleMatrix(int* mat, int ROWSIZE , int COLSIZE)
{
    int row1, col1, row2, col2;
    do{
        row1 = 1 + rand() % (ROWSIZE) ;
        row2 = 1 + rand() % (ROWSIZE) ;
        col1 = 1 + rand() % (COLSIZE) ;
        col2 = 1 + rand() % (COLSIZE) ;
    }while (row1 == row2 || col1 == col2);

}
```

the error point to ROWSIZE

Comment: If `ROWSIZE` and `COLSIZE` are fixed, then you probably don't need pass them to your functions. Just remove `int ROWSIZE , int COLSIZE` parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define COLSIZE 4
#define ROWSIZE 5
void creatGameMatrix(int* mat,  int ROWSIZE , int COLSIZE);
```

This makes no sense. It expands to

```
void creatGameMatrix(int* mat,  int 5, int 4);
```

Which is clearly not right (specifically function argument names must be identifiers and `4` and `5` are not identifiers). Options are either:

1. Don't pass parameters and use the #defines inside the routine
2. Name the parameters like `rowsize` and `colsize` and use those in the routine. Pass the values in using the `ROWSIZE` and `COLSIZE` defines.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use these macros as the names of function parameters. After the macros are expanded, you end up with:

```
void creatGameMatrix(int* mat,  int 5 , int 4);
void shuffleMatrix(int* mat, int 5 , int 4);
```

That makes no sense -- function parameters have to be valid variable names, not numbers.

Use different names for the function parameters, and then use the macros when you call the functions.

```
void creatGameMatrix(int* mat,  int rowsize , int colsize);
void shuffleMatrix(int* mat, int rowsize , int colsize);
```

Or you can simply omit these parameters entirely:

```
void creatGameMatrix(int* mat);
void shuffleMatrix(int* mat);
```

Comment: I changed it to say *valid variable names*

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare a function parameter called `ROWSIZE` because `ROWSIZE` is a #define.  What the pre-compiler will do is replace `ROWSIZE` with 5.  Same goes for `COLSIZE`  Which makes the header be `void shuffleMatrix(int* mat, int 5 , int 4);`.  That's not valid code.

Since you already `#defined` them, you can just remove them as parameters to your function as they will be available to use anywhere in that file.